# Get street name with Reverse Geocoding

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to get Street, City and Country with reverse geocoding using google map example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse, But all it gives me is `.formatted_address` not street, city and country.

Is there any way where I can get Street, City and Country separately ?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/53trvg6t/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.address_components` instead of `.formatted_address`, through Address Components you can break the result into different variables and then call it into your info window. [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/53trvg6t/2/)